# Loading data from flat file to database table with adding current columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, transformation

I want to load data from csv file with such columns

```
     ID | Time | Date
```

and in my database a table have such structure

```
     ID | Time | Date | Time+Date
```

I wounder if I can make any transformation to make this flow to datebase?

I know how to write select query and then insert data to database but I think there is a tool in ssis.

Comment: Just add an derived column after your flat file source, where you concatenate Time and Date

Comment: I don't know how to use SSIS to achieve that, I just start learning this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive added this into my CSV file:

```
ID Time     Date
----------------------
1  00:04:00 01-01-2017
2  00:02:00 01-02-2017
```

**This is how my SSIS Package Looks like**

[image]

**This is how my Derived Column looks like**

[image]

**This is the outcome in my table**
[image]

**UPDATE**

Just add a new derived column to get it into Datetime datatype

Like this:
[image]

**New Result with datatype DateTime**

[image]

Comment: but I have then string, not date time data type. Conversion doesnt work

Comment: Just cast it as a date then. Show your Time and date format.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial task if you use SQL Server Integration Services. Just use a Derived Column with an expression like

> [Time] + [Date]

to achieve this.